# How to directly can get specific routes when I use React(CRA) + Express routing

Tags: express

React Router (using React-router-dom)
/, /about, /contact

Express Router
/ => rendering react's built index.html

for preventing "can not get /about, /contact", I coded like that.

even CRA code is same as mine
(https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing)

but problem is when I want to get "http://www.example.com/about" directly, but It will redirect to "http://www.example.com/" becasue of that code.

What can I do?

---

```
// rendering react
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/client/build/index.html");
});

// for preventing cannot get
app.use("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/client/build/index.html");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

after struggle with ma code, I find the anwer.

you need to use reverse-proxy.

in my case I use Nginx.